# ModuleNotFoundError for a script, only when running from the CMD prompt, but not when running from anaconda prompt

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I need to be able to run a script from the CMD prompt for a project. In the past, I ran my script from the anaconda prompt with no problems. I tried initially running my script in the same fashion using conda run. When I do this, I get a ModuleNotFoundError for a module that is in anaconda. Specifically, it is numpy and pychrono that I am having an issue with, which I understand are packages that are within anaconda.

> conda run demo_VEH_DeformableSoil.py

Comment: A module is a library (.dll file) which you `import` (reference) in your Python script. Python must be able to find the library file containing the code of the functions referenced in your Python script. The environment variable `PYTHONPATH` holds usually the list of folder paths in which `python.exe` should search for the libraries files referenced in Python script with just the file name without path. The environment variable `PYTHONPATH` as well as also `PATH` are definitely defined different between standard __cmd__ environment and __Anaconda__ environment.

Comment: Please read in the Python documentation the chapters [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) and [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) to get knowledge on how Python really works as it looks like you are coding Python scripts without knowing that.

Comment: You are correct, I am very new to Python. Thank you for the advice, I will check up on all of these leads

Answer (score 1):

you can still use `envp`

```
pip install envp
```

Create a text file called `requirements.txt` and inside it write the module names that your project needs so it can run..

Inside the directory that has the project do:

```
envp piplock
```